# Flatten array with stack

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to flatten an array iteratively with a stack ( or rather in this example splicing in the result array rather than adding / removing from a stack ) up to a specific depth ( Not for any practical reason other than to learn ).

So far I have

```
function flatten(arr, depth = 1) {

    let flat = [];
    let i = 0;

    let d = depth;

    for (let elem of arr) {
        flat.push(elem);
        d = depth;

        while(i < flat.length) {
            if (Array.isArray(flat[i]) && d !== 0) {
                flat.splice(i, 1, ...flat[i]);
                d--;

            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }


    }

    return flat;
}
```

but it falls over if I have a level such as [[3], 4, [5, [6]] as once it goes into the depth of '3' it doesn't back out.

Is there a simple modification I can make?

The original array I was using is `flatten([[1],2,[[3], 'ddd', [4,[5]]]], 2)` , where I would expect the result to be [1,2,3,'ddd',4, [5]]

I also have the same issue if I implement it normally using a stack.

Comment: Doesn't changing the depth from 2 to 3 get you the result you expect? Perhaps your depth  value in the function is just "off by one" ?

Comment: No the problem it seems to have is once it goes up a depth it never changes back

So if I have `[[1],2,[3, 'ddd', [4,[5]]]` it works - but if I put the 3 in an array then that seems to then take go up a depth, and then when it gets to 4 it doesn't add 4 but instead adds [4, [5]]

Comment: You should try with recursion!

Comment: As far as I can tell, if you want a depth limit, you also need to track where you are at each depth so that you know how to back out. Recursion implicitly tracks that for you but you're not using recursion so you have to do it yourself. (Also, I think there's a way to do it without tracking if you don't set a depth limit.)

Comment: I'm trying to do that - that is what d is doing. For each new item in the main array ( for of loop ) d will be the passed depth as it's effectively the first level, and then I decrement d when I push to the output array.

Comment: I think it might be best to do debugging such that you aren't making assumptions about what it's doing. `console.log('array',i,d,flat)` after `if` and `console.log('other',i,d,flat)` after `else`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think with `concat` and `reduce` you can get it done in a quite clean way:

```js
const flatten = (array, depth) => {
  if(!depth) return array;
  while(depth > 0) {
    array = array.reduce((pre, curr) => pre.concat(curr), []);
    depth--;
  }
  return array;
}

const flat = flatten([1, 2, ['a', 3], [4, [6, 4]], 3, [1, 3], [[['a', 2], 2, 'b'], 'c', 3], 4], 2);
console.log(flat)
```

Basically what it does is iterate over the array `depth` times.
Each pass it will `reduce` the array to another array which is the `concat` of each element in the previous array. The gist is that `concat` has two different possible invocations:

1. when invoked with a non-array parameter it simply adds the element to the original array
2. when invoked with an array parameter it adds each element of the given array to the original one

So basically the core of "flattening" is already done by `concat` itself, you just need to keep doing that `depth` times.

Comment: This is a neat approach, but the issue with this is the complexity would be n^depth - as you will reduce over the already flattened items. So worst case ( I think ) would be an already flattened array, where I think with the stack approach you get linear time.

Comment: Uhm I believe if you iterate `n` items `depth` times you get `n*depth` iterations. Which unless `depth` is meant to grow freely is just linear itself.